# Spring My-batis MapperScannerConfigurer not resolving dat source place holder values

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper

After adding MapperScannerConfigurer  bean configuration to the configuration  xml to autowire my-batis mappers, getting below datasource bean creation error for placeholder issue. looks like spring unable to resolve the dynamic data source properties from property file. Configuration has PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer defination as well to retrieve the datasource properties(min pool size and max pool size ) from class path file. even though having PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean configuration, Integration test failing with below error. Basically it is unable to resolve dynamic properties. Any help is much appreciated..
This is just spring and my-batis based project and I there is no spring boot.

Spring version 5.3
my-batis-spring 2.0.6

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${datasource.minpoolsize}"

```
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.mapper" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="appProperties"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>
                classpath:configs/application.yaml
            </value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of configuring MapperScannerConfigurer in the xml, I used @MapperScan on
Spring configuration bean which resolved the issue.